# DropDownList display different DataTables upon selection has messed up header and old data in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a dropdownlist. When a user select a value from the drop down, a datatables appears. I can only get the first table to appear right, the subsequent selection from the drop down will have the order of the header and value all messed up. Some header titles from the previous datatables are still on the new datatables header. The styling is gone. If I click on a column to sort, the styling is back but the headers and body still have wrong data.

My code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('#compTable').remove(); //tried this but nothing loads.
        $('.ddlCom').change(function () {

            var comID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                "url": 'CompTableJson.ashx?comID=' + comID,
                "dataType": "json",
                "success": function (json) {
                    $('#compTable').dataTable({
                        "aaData": json.aaData,
                        "aoColumns": json.aoColumns,
                        "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bScrollInfinite": true,
                        "bScrollCollapse": true,
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "bDeferRender": true,
                        "iDisplayLength": 100,
                        "sScrollY": "1000px"
                    });
                }

            });
        });

    });    

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figured it out. Not only I have to fnDestroy() the datatables but also clear out all the HTML